# mp3 header information reader not working

Tags: java, javasound

hi all
i get bit rate from the following code . i have a song with bit rate is 128kbps. but it print 0 only. please help me.
code:
      import java.io.File;
      import java.io.IOException;

```
  import org.farng.mp3.MP3File;
  import org.farng.mp3.TagException;
  import org.farng.mp3.id3.AbstractID3v1;
  import org.farng.mp3.id3.AbstractID3v2;


  public class ID3Reader {
File sourcefile;
MP3File mp3file;

public ID3Reader(String filename) {
        sourcefile = new File(filename);
        try {
            mp3file = new MP3File(sourcefile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TagException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

public static void main( String[] args )
{

    ID3Reader id3reader = new ID3Reader("D:\\Mp3\\taxi.mp3");
    id3reader.displayinformations();
}

private void displayinformations() {
    String title="", artist="", album="", genre="", year="";
    System.out.println("bit rate"+mp3file.getBitRate()); // print bit rate as 0(zero).
    if(mp3file.hasID3v1Tag()){

        AbstractID3v1 tag = mp3file.getID3v1Tag();
        if(tag != null){
            try{ title = tag.getSongTitle(); }catch(Exception e){}
            try{ artist = tag.getLeadArtist(); }catch(Exception e){}
            try{ album = tag.getAlbumTitle(); }catch(Exception e){}
            try{ genre = tag.getSongGenre(); }catch(Exception e){}
            try{ year = tag.getYearReleased(); }catch(Exception e){}

        }
    }else if(mp3file.hasID3v2Tag()){
        AbstractID3v2 tag = mp3file.getID3v2Tag();
        if(tag != null){
            title = tag.getFrame("TT2").toString();
            artist = tag.getFrame("TP1").toString();
            album = tag.getFrame("TAL").toString();
            year = tag.getFrame("TYE").toString();
            genre = tag.getFrame("TCO").toString();
        }
    }   
    System.out.println("Titre : " + title);
    System.out.println("Artiste : " + artist);
    System.out.println("Album : " + album);
    System.out.println("Genre : " + genre);
    System.out.println("Annee : " + year);
}       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call `mp3file.seekMP3Frame();` before attempting to retrieve bitrate, this method will read the file headers including the bitrate.

Comment: thanks it works i get bit rate afte calling the method. is there any way to calculate bpm by using bit rate.please help me.

Comment: Hehe, no, bpm is completely different.

Comment: how to calculate bpm. please tell some ideas. please guide me. thanks.

Comment: Calculating BPM is not an easy thing to do. Effectively the machine has to 'listen' to the sound and make a guess as to where the 'beats' are. There's third-party software to do just this.

Comment: is there any programmatic way?

Comment: As a side note, the BPM calculated by machines might not always correspond to the how humans perceive the tempo. You might want to take this into account before you rely too much on that parameter. http://www.icmpc8.umn.edu/proceedings/ICMPC8/PDF/AUTHOR/MP040237.PDF

Answer (score 0):

A little off topic, but try JAudioTagger and see if that gives you better results. I've tried a few libraries which reads/writes MP3 tags, and JAudioTagger is the one I've been most happy with.

http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/examples_id3.jsp